# Batch file fails to copy a file from one directory to another, then rename it in windows 10. The resulting file is corrupted

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename

I have an excel report that generates each day. I need to copy (or move), and rename that file, so that it can be shared out of Dropbox. So I have a .bat file that is supposed to copy to a new location, and rename the file. This part is working, the report is being generated successfully and is usually around 800kb. But the copied and renamed file is corrupted and only has one line, and is less than 1kb. I've researched this quite a bit - it seems like a simple task, and the code appears to be proper.

I would sincerely appreciate some pointers. Thank you.

```
REM THIS PROCEDURE WILL MOVE THE LOCALLY.XLS FILE FROM REPORTS TO THE DROPBOX FOLDER, AND RENAME IT TO LOCALLY.XLS

COPY /Y R:\v9reports\*Locally*.xls R:\DROPBOX\locally\Locally.xls

EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/1363049/unexpected-results-with-copy-command-and-excel-files

The copy command doesn't work with wildcards in an excel file's name.